# perl regex extracted from one file to use on a variable

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file containing search and replace string in a single line.

And I am reading that file, using split to separate search and replace string
and apply it on a variable.

---

**File:**

```
(.*) pre_$1
```

---

**Perl Code:**

```
$str = "a";

$line = < FILEHANDLE>; # Read above file.Contains (.*) pre_$1

my ($ss,$rs) = split /\s/,$line;

$str =~ s/$ss/$rs/ee;
```

---

This seems to be not working.

I tried to look online, one result is close which is wrap the replace string in both single and double quotes.

i.e.:

```
$rs = '"pre_$1"';
```

This works if its in the script, but if I read from file I done see any replacement.

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Please note the answer post suggested has both the search and replace string in the script. But I am reading them from a file (as noted in my question). I have tried the solution and it didn't work (also noted in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s//$rs/ee` expects `$rs` to contains valid Perl code. `pre_$1` is not valid Perl code. It's a very bad idea to expect the user to provide Perl code anyway.

Solution:

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

gsub_modify($str, $ss, $rs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The end user here are Perl aware. 

Also the problem is I need to use inbuild functions here.
I have found a workaround, but it's very crude.

`
my $line = <$fh>;

my ($ss,$rs) = split /\s/,$line;

if ($str =~ m/$ss/){

  my $match = $1;

  $rs =~ s/(\$\w+)/$match/eeg;

  $str = $rs;

}
`

Comment: Re "*I need to use inbuild functions here.*", If you can use the code we post on SO, you can use the code we post on CPAN.

Comment: Re "*`s/(\$\w+)/$match/eeg`*", That should be `s/(\$\w+)/$match/g`

Comment: I work on remote machine where I cannot access internet and ftp isn't allowed. So I cannot install String::Substitution (PERL v5.16.3). I changed the eeg to g. Thanks

Comment: That's not true. You can get your own script on it, so you can get the module on it too!

Comment: I appreciate the answer but please stop speculating on my work env without info. Obviously I am duplicating a piece of code to show the issue here.

Comment: I didn't do any speculating; you indicated that you able to change code on the machine. If you can do that, you can install String::Substitution. There is no difference between a script and a module.